# React Native TabView not working after generating an apk

Tags: typescript, react-native, tabview

I am using a TabView from react-native-tab-view, it works fine when when I am running my application with expo and scan the QR Code with my android device, but when I generate an apk and open the application, it does not work.

```
 return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingComponent />
  ) : person? (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
      renderScene={renderScene}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
      style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
    />
  ) : (
    <View></View>
  )
}
```

Comment: please try react-navigation bottom/top tab

Comment: you can use this official documentation for the tab view
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75093385/react-native-tabview-not-working-after-generating-an-apk

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, I only had to update to the latest version of Expo.